# How to open respective View when clicked on link in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to open respective View when clicked on link in MVC.

_Layout

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Racing", "Reports", "Reports", null, null, "RacingFilter", null, new { @id = "RacingId" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sire", "Reports", "Reports", null, null, "SireReportsFilter", null, new { @id = "SireId" })</li>
```

Reports View

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">        
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#racing">Racing Reports</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sire">Sire Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">           
        <div id="racing" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Racing/Racing.cshtml", Model.clsRacing)
        </div>
        <div id="sire" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/SireReports/SireReports.cshtml", Model.clsSireReports)
        </div>

    </div>
```

Jquery

```
   $('#RacingId').click(function (e)            
            $('#racing').show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not working, because the jquery click event will fire before you are redirected to new page. You can to it like this.

You can have your actionlinks to send another parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Racing", "Reports", "Reports", null, null, "RacingFilter", new { tab = "RacingTab" }, new { @id = "RacingId" })
@Html.ActionLink("Sire", "Reports", "Reports", null, null, "SireReportsFilter", new { tab = "SireTab" }, new { @id = "SireId" })
```

In your controler you retrieve this value and save it in Viewbag, or add it in your model to pass it into page.

```
 public ActionResult Reports(string tab)
 {
      this.ViewBag.Tab = tab;
      return this.View(Model);
 }
```

and in your reports view you can do this

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#@ViewBag.Tab").tab('show');
       });
   </script>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">        
        <li><a id="RacingTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#racing">Racing Reports</a></li>
        <li><a id="SireTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#sire">Sire Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">           
        <div id="racing" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Racing/Racing.cshtml", Model.clsRacing)
        </div>
        <div id="sire" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/SireReports/SireReports.cshtml", Model.clsSireReports)
        </div>
    </div>
```

This should work.

Dont forget that Viewbag will last only one request, so if you are doing any redirecting on controller then you need to do a little tweaking.

Comment: Oh, i got what you were trying to do. I have modified my answer.